# EL resolving bean name

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, cdi

Having a @Named Bean: `HelloBean`

In a JSF page, Why this reference is correct:

```
#{helloBean.var1}
```

And this doesn't appear to: (IDE Warning: "Can't resolve variable Name")

```
#{HelloBean.var1}
```

Comment: How do you name your instance variables? You don't do `HelloBean HelloBean = new HelloBean()`, but you also do `HelloBean helloBean = new HelloBean()`, right? It's just the standard Java naming convention.

Comment: OK, then what we're referring in JSF is an object, not the class itself. EL makes sure we're referring to that particular class with the rule written by @perissf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Oracle's [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbak.html):

> The @Named qualifier allows you to access the bean by using the bean name, with the first letter in lowercase.

The same rule applies also for [ManagedBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) annotation:

> If the value of the name  attribute is unspecified or is the empty String, the managed-bean-name is derived from taking the unqualified class name portion of the fully qualified class name and converting the first character to lower case

Comment: Sorry, this is the docs for ManagedBean annotation, not for Named. Let me correct the answer.